# Can one "cross-shape" as a Druid?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, druid, wild-shape

As a Druid with multiple per-day uses of Wild Shape, can I "cross shape" directly from one wild form into another without going through my humanoid form first?  (Say, starting off as a bird perched on a treelimb and then shaping directly to a panther, or jumping into the water as a wolf and then shaping directly to a fish.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As written, [Wild Shape](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm#wildShape) works like the ability [Alternate Form](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#alternateForm)*. And that ability has the following entry:

> The creature retains the spell-like abilities and supernatural attacks of its old form.

Wild Shape is a [Supernatural](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#supernaturalAbilities) ability, and thus, is retained while wild shaped. So, as long as you still have more uses to burn, you can wild shape while you wild shape.

<sub>*Except for minor details that are not relevant to this question.</sub>